# Get maximum possible extent for a rectangle in a given space with obstacles

Tags: .net, math

I'm dealing with the following problem:

There is a grid with empty cells (empty cells shown in white). Individual cells in this grid are already "occupied" with elements (elements shown in orange).

Now I have the starting point of a rectangle (in this case row 6, col 3). This rectangle should occupy as many free cells as possible. The rectangle should stop at orange elements or when the grid ends.

The attached screenshot shows 2 grid scenarios and their solutions.

The left scenario would return

```
width = 2
height = 5
```

The right scenario would return

```
width = 1
height = 5
```

I have tried so many times to write an easy, simple code that would return the maximum width and height of that rectangle, but in the end I always end up with a long and ugly code.

Is there a clean, short mathematical solution for this, or is this simple a problem that is not as easy as it looks like in the first place?

Thank you.
[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent the grid by a 0-1 matrix where a `1` corresponds to an obstacle.

If the grid is `m x n` and `(a,b)` are the 0-based row and column indices of the starting cell, then `width = n-b` represents the maximum possible width of a rectangle starting at that cell, irrespective of any obstacles. This is the current width. Now, start scanning down the column from that cell until either the bottom edge or an obstacle is encountered. For each cell in that column, start scanning right until either an obstacle or the current width is reached. If an obstacle is encountered first, decrease the current width. Append the current width to a list of widths (whether or not the current width had been decreased).

At this stage, you have a list of widths, with one width for every potential height. Just scan over this list, multiplying each width by the corresponding height (which would be 1 + the 0-based list index). Return the pair (height,width) which maximized the product height*width.

A Python implementation:

```
def find_max_rect(grid,a,b):
    if grid[a][b] == 1: return (0,0)
    m = len(grid) #number of rows
    n = len(grid[0]) #number of columns
    width = n-b #maximum possible width given starting column
    widths = [] 
    i = a
    while i < m and grid[i][b] == 0:
        #scan right from (i,b+1) until a 1 or current width is hit
        for j in range(b+1,b+width):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                #an obstacle forces width to contract
                width = j-b #number of steps before obstacle
                break #out of inner loop
        widths.append(width)
        i += 1      
    max_area = 0
    max_at = -1
    for i,width in enumerate(widths):
        if (i+1)*width > max_area:
            max_area = (i+1)*width
            max_at = i
    return (max_at + 1,widths[max_at])
```

Tested like:

```
test_grid = [[1,0,1,1,0],
             [0,1,0,0,0],
             [0,1,0,0,0],
             [0,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,1,0],
             [0,0,0,1,0],
             [0,0,0,0,1],
             [0,0,0,0,0],
             [1,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,1],
             [0,1,0,0,0]]

print(find_max_rect(test_grid,6,2)) #prints (5,2)
```

**On Edit**: I realized that there is little reason to store the candidate widths only to iterate over them just once. Instead, you can keep track of the best area on the fly. The following code is functionally equivalent but more efficient:

```
def find_max_rect(grid,a,b):
    if grid[a][b] == 1: return (0,0)
    m = len(grid) #number of rows
    n = len(grid[0]) #number of columns
    current_height = 0
    current_width = n - b #maximum possible width given starting column
    max_area = 0
    best_height, best_width = current_height, current_width

    i = a
    while i < m and grid[i][b] == 0:
        current_height += 1
        #scan right from (i,b + 1) until a 1 or current width is hit
        for j in range(b + 1,b + current_width):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                #an obstacle forces width to contract
                current_width = j - b #number of steps before obstacle
                break
        #decide if the best should be adjusted
        current_area = current_height * current_width
        if  current_area > max_area:
            best_area, best_height, best_width = current_area, current_height, current_width
        i+=1
    return best_height, best_width
```